# including file with if else condition

Tags: php, mysql

i am including payment.php but only in case of if image type is equal to "map" else rest of the html content without including payment.php.

for Example

```
<?php
include('aaa.php');
$url=$_GET['url'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM maps WHERE url='$url'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $name=$row['name'];$metaTitle=$row['metaTitle'];$metaDesc=$row['metaDesc'];$metaKeyword=$row['metaKeyword'];$imageType=$row['imageType'];
?>
```

some content appears. i need to write php code for below line

```
if imageType(name of field in table)= map
then include external file "payment.php"
else
html content without indluding payment.php file.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($imageType == "map") {
    include('payment.php');
}
//html content here
```

Comment: Its not geting parsed

Comment: Is payment.php in the same directory as the script you're executing?

Comment: yes its in the same directory, shall i paste the complete code here?

Comment: Maybe you should activate error_reporting and display_errors. PHP should've thrown an error like `Undefined function imageType used ...`.